# Single page secure Ajax form - for payments with credit card, corss-domain solution required

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

I am developing single page Ajax application (pure HTML/CSS/Javascript, jQuery, any communication with the PHP server side (e.g. reading offers and prices and saving the completed purchases) is done through jQuery AJAX requests. HTML form is used only for reading credit card data, they are submitted to PHP server page and all the processing (communication with the payment provider) is done on PHP server

All is going OK, except that I have concerns (maybe unfounded) whether it is possible to accept credit card data in the Ajax form. The main concerns is:
- if usual HTML/PHP form is submitted (e.g. POST submit), then all the traffic between brwoser and server is secure (assuming that HTML/PHP form is with https url, etc). But what happens with the AJAX trafic, especially if it is submitted to the other domain (using pJSON)? Is this traffic crypted?

Maybe it is not good idea to capture credit card data with AJAX form at all?

Comment: How is the data being submitted to the other domain? With GET or POST? Why don't you just post to your server and have your server make the call to the other domain?

Comment: I am using jQuery Ajax and I guess that I am using GET request (with some data are encoded in the query string... I see that it is becoming bad...), maybe there is no way to use POST request. Regarding use of crossdomain solution - the form will be hosted on the other page/server over which we don't control.

Comment: Regarding security and sending data in GET query string parameters. One possible solution is to encode the sensitive data with the public key of the server and then put some cryptic message in the query string parameters. It should work but I can not believe that there is not already established good practice in such cases.